# javascript loop exceeding call stack

Tags: javascript

I mostly use LUA and I've been trying to make something with JavaScript with some help from a friend, and I don't understand why this loop is exceeding the call stack.

```
var myVar;
(function loop() {
    for (var x = 0, ln = 3; x < ln; x++) {
        myVar = setTimeout(function(i) {
            console.log(i);
        }, x * 333, x);
        clearTimeout(myVar);
    }
    loop();
}());
```

Comment: `clearTimeout(myVar);` <-- Why create the timeout than clear it?

Comment: you're calling `loop` from within `loop`, leading to infinite recursion

Comment: you're calling loop from within loop, *unconditionally*, leading to infinite recursion

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a recursive loop with a progressive delay. It works pretty much the same in JS as it does in other languages -- you set up an edge condition that stops the loop on a certain condition and then recurse. You can do that in a timeout. There's no need to clear it unless you had to stop a timeout already started. I would do it more like this:

```js
var start = 0;
var ln = 3;

(function loop(i) {
  if (i > ln) return // edge condition
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(i);
    loop(i + 1); // recurse
  }, i * 333, i);
})(start);
```